# Is there a OSX Yosemite-like icon theme?

Tags: unity, themes, icons, macosx, icon-themes

I'm wondering if there's any icon theme out there that resembles the new icons of Mac OSX Yosemite. I don't mean something exactly like it, as I don't want to make Ubuntu look like a Mac. I'm looking for something similar with a minimalistic appearance that is not just completely flat like Google's Material Design or the Paper icon theme. Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you looking for the icons in [Macbuntu](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html)?

Comment: Have you found your answer or any of the answers helped? if yes, try accepting or give feedback if didn't work